# How to add a new field image?

Tags: views

These are the field thats I already created:

> [image]

And this is how my page currently looks like:

> [image]

The first image is the background of this page.

I want to add field image on the blue line. But when I add new field of image it doesn't show the second image.

Any suggestions about how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please Check 1. In Manage display whether that image field has a setting hidden. If hidden it will not show up. 2. are you uploading image for node while creating that node? 3. Check the CSS of that image, whether it is hiding image due to CSS.

Comment: Does image show up in view preview?

Answer (score 0):

Add the field to the content type; check your node/page template, and add some code to print the new image field. If there is no custom template for your content type, create one and customize the output to your wishes.
You might also check the display settings for the content type, and make sure your image is displayed.